# Explanations about ADAM Optimizer algorithm

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent

I'm a beginner in Machine learning and i'm searching for some optimizer for the gradient descent. I've searched many topics about that, and did a state of art of all these optimizers. I have just one problem, and i can't figure it out. Don't judge me please, but i would like to know ?

Are we using ADAM optimizer alone or are we obliged to combine it with the SGD ? I didn't understand if it works alone or if it's here to optimize NOT the neural network but the SGD of the neural network?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: ADAM is a standalone optimizer, so no need to be combined with SGD. It is kind of advanced flavor of classical SGD. Have you seen this post: https://machinelearningmastery.com/adam-optimization-algorithm-for-deep-learning/? I think it has all you need to know about ADAM, and it is even compared with others.

Comment: Yep, as an aside, just about any optimizer you will come across is still a form of SGD, just with fancier handling of different weights and learning rate over time

Answer (score 1):

Adam optimization is an extension of stochastic gradient descent (SGD) optimization.

SGD maintains a single learning rate for all weight updates and the learning rate does not change during training.

Adam optimization can have a different learning rate for each weight and change the learning rate during training.